# Linux shell send an email with attachment

Tags: linux, shell, email

I'm desperately for send an email with an attachment, on Linux shell.

I send an email without attachment using

```
cat $repert/$DATE.txt | mail -s "Démarrage de a - $DATE" destin@domain.com
```

I tried to install Mutt to make the attachment, but, using the same receiver, it told me that the domain is blacklisted.
I also tried to use the "-x" and "-a" options with the mail command but it doesn't work.

The attachments I tried are images and compressed files.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: How doesn't `-a` work? What exactly happens?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If your domain is blacklisted, how you send the message is not the problem at all. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam